# Pyqt5: How to limit the dragging area of a QPushButton in QMainWindow?

Tags: pyqt5, qwidget, qpushbutton

On dragging the QPushButton in QWidget, it works ***until it disapears*** once it pass (cross) the border of the MainWindow (QWidget)

##### I would like to Limit this QPushButton to don't cross the border of it's container, but to remain visible just winthin the QWidget

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class DragButton(QPushButton):
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.__mousePressPos = None
        self.__mouseMovePos = None
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.__mousePressPos = event.globalPos()
            self.__mouseMovePos = event.globalPos()
        super(DragButton, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
            # adjust offset from clicked point to origin of widget
            currPos = self.mapToGlobal(self.pos())
            globalPos = event.globalPos()
            diff = globalPos - self.__mouseMovePos
            newPos = self.mapFromGlobal(currPos + diff)
            self.move(newPos)
            self.__mouseMovePos = globalPos
        super(DragButton, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if self.__mousePressPos is not None:
            moved = event.globalPos() - self.__mousePressPos 
            if moved.manhattanLength() > 3:
                event.ignore()
                return
        super(DragButton, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)

def clicked():
    print ("click as normal!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    w   = QWidget()
    w.resize(800,600)
    button = DragButton("Drag", w)
    button.clicked.connect(clicked)
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the requirement is ensuring that the child is within the boundaries of the parent, you need to check if the children `rect()`, translated to the new position, is within that area, *before* moving it.

Note that to achieve "self" movement, it's not necessary to continuously translate the global position.

```
class DragButton(QPushButton):
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.__mousePressPos = None
        self.__mouseMovePos = None
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.__mousePressPos = event.globalPos()
            self.__mouseMovePos = event.pos()
        super(DragButton, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
            delta = event.pos() - self.__mouseMovePos
            newPos = self.pos() + delta
            if self.parent():
                geo = self.rect().translated(newPos)
                parentRect = self.parent().rect()
                if geo.x() < 0:
                    geo.moveLeft(0)
                elif geo.right() > parentRect.right():
                    geo.moveRight(parentRect.right())
                if geo.y() < 0:
                    geo.moveTop(0)
                elif geo.bottom() > parentRect.bottom():
                    geo.moveBottom(parentRect.bottom())
                self.move(geo.topLeft())
            else:
                self.move(newPos)
        super(DragButton, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)
```

Also consider that dragging on an enabled button is not a very good idea, as it might result in unwanted, unintuitive and unexpected behavior. Your implementation shows this, since if the button is moved beyond the 3 pixel limit, it will stay pressed.

Comment: this class DragButton(QPushButton):  creates a New button, but is there a way to direct inherite the button from my .ui file ?    and apply the attributes of your class (since i'm styling the button on Qt Designer and loading it with loadUi()). "dragbtn" is name of the button in Qt Designer

Comment: You need to do some research about "widget promotion" in Designer.

Comment: please do you have a youtube channel or a group,...I want to learn from you